# Configuring one web.config file for different servers

Tags: iis-7, web-config

Is there a way to configure a web.config file to execute it's rules only if there is a match to a server name?

For example, we have two servers: WebDev (for development) and WebLive (live web server)

On the live server, we have a URL rewrite rule that configures a canonical name, but when we synchronize those sites (thereby copying the web.config file back to the dev) and run it on the development platform, the canonical rule kicks in and send us to the live site instead of keeping us on the development platform. I can exclude the web.config from our synchronization, but was seeking an alternative.

Kinda like...

```
<apply rule to WebLive>
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.org$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.org/{R:1}" />
</rule>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010, you now can apply a transformation to your web.config depending on the build configuration.

When creating a web.config, you can expand the file in the solution explorer, and you will see two files:

1. Web.Debug.Config
2. Web.Release.Config

They contains transformation code that can be used to:

- Change the connection string
- Remove debugging trace and settings
- Register error pages

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Can this be done outside the context of Visual Studio? We don't use VS. Thx.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment above? I'd like to set up a single web.config on our production and development servers, but I don't use Visual Studio. Thanks.